# Excel graph plot values between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is there a way to plot a stacked graph values in Excel within a range of date/time?

[image: Table]

Here's what I'm expecting for the graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: sure, there is. What you've tried? Why that didn't work? What exactly you need? Maybe adding a handdrawn sketch would help us to understand what exactly you need.

Comment: Hi, sure. I've added a graph sample of what i'm expecting. I have no clue on how to do it with Excel as the graph doesn't support a range of dates for multiple values

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the relationship between the sketched chart and the data is? I'm not sure I follow it.

Comment: You've made a good start at writing a good question, but it needs a bit more work. Please try harder to *explain* the chart that you want. (1) For example, do you want the chart to show only three of the seven fruit items that you have data for? How is it supposed to decide which three? If you want to chart all items, then why have you shown us data for seven but shown only three in the chart? (2) How does the chart work? You have two rows of data for "Cherry". One has a start date of 9 November and one has a start date of 16 November. They both have an end date of 6 February. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And yet the column for "Cherry" starts before 7 November and stretches all the way into November of 2017. The values for "Apple" go up to November ***2018 (!)**,* but the "Apple" column cuts off at some unlabeled point in mid-2017. The rows for "Cherry" have values of 400 and 280 (for a total of 680), but the chart column for "Cherry" goes up only to around 580 (or maybe 600). The chart column for "Apple" goes up only to 400, even though the "Apple" data are 280, 400, 400 and 280, and *all* of their start/end ranges overlap (so why aren't they all added together?). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Please try harder to present the information clearly. (3a) I have trouble reading your handwriting. The top three "values" along the "Y" axis of your chart, which I guess are 600, 500, and 400, look like "800", "Feb", and "Gdo". (3b) For your information, many people in English-speaking countries write dates as mm/dd/yyyy, so 07/11 is July 11 and 15/11 is not a valid date. Obviously you are using dd/mm/yyyy format. Please make things clearer for us and use dd‑mmmm (e.g., 7‑November) format. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3c) Simplify your data. It should be possible to show what you want to show with a collection of dates that are all in the same year. (3d) You have dates in your data going out to 2018, which is outside the range of your chart. That's confusing. (3e) Since you're talking about dates that are months and even years apart, you should not include times — ESPECIALLY when they're all the same. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3f) Showing alternating rows of a table in alternating colors is a useful technique when those rows stretch all the way across the page, with ten or more columns, and when some rows are more than one line high. Neither of those conditions is true for your table.  But you have a bunch of different fruit items, in no obvious order or pattern, with different numbers of rows for different items. It would be a lot more useful if you color-coded the rows of data by item, so, for example, all "Orange" rows would be orange.

Comment: To add to Scott's questions (I think, unless I missed it), the stacking you show in your chart seems complex.  It isn't clear whether (or what) things are additive, or just layered in front of each other.  Can you explain what you want the chart to indicate?

Comment: @fixer1234: Well, my question #2 (How does the chart work? Why "Cherry" data of 680 but the chart goes up only to around 580 (or maybe 600); why aren't the "Apple" values all added together?) is similar in focus to your question, but if you missed it amongst all my verbiage, maybe Ali did too.